# SPSS Remove extension bundle

Tags: spss

How can you remove an extension bundle from SPSS 23, after you have installed it ? Under `Utilities/Extension bundles` menu, you can only `view installed bundles` (which is read-only) and `edit`(which allows only for editing the details of an extension, not removing it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Statistics 24, the Extensions > Extension Hub menu takes you to a display where you can click on the Installed tab and then check Uninstall extension.

In earlier versions, the removal process is manual.  You can uninstall the dialog box using Utilities > Custom Dialogs > Custom Dialog Builder.  Then do File > Uninstall.

If you want to also remove the implementation, you need to manually delete those files.  Look at SHOW EXT to see where they might be, and then just delete the .xml, .py, and .R files  on that path that have the extension name.  (Or .sps and .java files if those languages were used to create the extension.)  There will also be a subdirectory with the extension name that should be removed.  However, in most cases it is just the menus that people want to clean up.  The other files are too small to worry about.

Comment: I am using SPSS 23, the Extension is (was) written in Python, and it did not have a dialog - just some code. I already did as you suggested. `SHOW EXT.` points to `C:\ProgramData\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\23\extensions` and `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\23\extensions`, and they are both empty. Yet my custom extension is still showing up in syntax and in the Utilities menu... :)

Comment: In the installed extensions list?  Do you still have the spe file in the search list?  And did you restart Statistics after deleting?

Comment: What happens when you try to run it?

Comment: It is still shown under `Utilities->...->View installed extensions`, and it is also available in the syntax, if I type it's first couple of letters - the autocomplete suggests its name. If I run it via syntax, I get the error about the module not being loaded. But the code was broken anyway, so I used to get the same message even when the Extension files were there. The .spe file is long gone as well. Since removing it, I restarted SPSS several times, and also the computer once. Maybe Statistics has some cache stored somewhere....?

Comment: Considering just the Syntax Editor for now, the only way it can know about the extension command syntax is via the XML file that defines it.  Check each of the extensions directories listed by SHOW EXTPATH.  It has to be in one of those on that list.  Remember also that while the convention is for the xml file to have the same name as the extension, it is the Name attribute in that file that determines the name of the command, not the xml filename.  Happy hunting.